# Влияет ли различие адреса домена и расположения сервера на продивжение в поисковиках?

Tags: seo

Если адрес сайта в казахстанской зоне(www.somesite.kz), а сервер в России, будет ли это как-либо влиять на положение сайта в поисковиках? Есть ли какие либо нюансы в сео, продвижении сайта по этому поводу?

Comment: Сейчас конечно набегут всякие сеошники и скажут "да, там куча мелочей, на за денежку мы тебе все устроем". По факту - делайте адекватный контент и Ваши страницы будут подыматься во всех нормальных поисковиках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы развеять сомнения...

- Идем [google.kz](http://google.kz) и вводим запрос
     **хабрахабр**
- Идем [google.ru](http://google.ru) и вводим тот же
     **хабрахабр**

В результате видим что во втором случае казахстанского хабра в выдаче и рядом нет

Если проделать аналогичное с Яшей, выдача не столь радует глаз и сама поисковая система не ахти.

Соответственно зона домена играет большую роль чем сервер.

Отвечая конкретно на вопрос, если время отклика сервера нормальное то особого влияние не будет. А в целом по большому счету 90% зависит от зоны домена и конечно же конткнта.

Answer (score 0):

Нюансов нет, сервер не причем. 
Важно присвоение региона сайту и региональности запроса.
Нужно смотреть откуда хотите черпать трафик(из какого города и страны)
Но все это мелочи. Главное - содержимое